# Unable to get QGraphicsView in QFormLayout to expand vertically

Tags: qt, qgraphicsview, qlayout

I've inherited a Qt code base with an Editor class based on QWidget. The Editor is set up to automatically use a QFormLayout as its layout, and so much related code assumes the QFormLayout that I can't realistically re-code for another layout.

The problem - the editor I'm working on will have an interactive QGraphicsView that should resize to fill the Editor's space. Unfortunately, it will only resize horizontally, not vertically. The QGraphicsView (referenced by QGraphicsView *m_view) is added to the layout as follows:

```
void EditorSubclass::initialize(...)
{
    ...
    QFormLayout* fl = qobject_cast<QFormLayout*>(this->layout());
    ...
    fl->addRow(m_view); // m_view is an instance of a QGraphicsView subclass
    ...
}
```

(the Editor class sets the layout, which is why this subclass just retrieves it instead of creating a new one)

m_view is the only thing added to the QFormLayout. I have tried getting it to expand vertically using multiple combinations of size hints, size policies, size constraints, field growth policies - you name it. No matter what I do, m_view sizes its height to whatever minimum size was set for it (75 pixels if I don't use setMinimumSize or setMinimumHeight). I checked the inherited Editor class, but it does not do anything that appears to affect sizing.

I've read in other similar questions that QFormLayout rows not resizing vertically is the normal behavior. The workarounds have tended to involve using a different layout, but that's not a realistic option here. A question asked 2-1/2 years ago - "[QSpacerItem In QFormLayout - Vertical Expand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13828657/qspaceritem-in-qformlayout-vertical-expand)" - had an intriguing reply involving "a layer of indirection by putting [an] HBoxLayout into a QWidget", but I can't figure out how to try that out from the description given, and don't have enough reputation to post a comment asking for details (which might be futile on a thread that old anyway).

So - does anyone know of a way to finagle QFormLayout into allowing my m_view to fill the available height and width?

Comment: Hi, if m_view is really the only widget in the QFormLayout (or whatever other layout type), your m_view widget should fill its parent widget (EditorSubclass). If not, the only posibility is you add a size constraint somewhere (in the code or with Qt designer). Just try with an other new random widget to be sure that you problem comes from the m_view widget itself.

Comment: The problem doesn't appear to be in the m_view as I've tried using other widgets (singly and in combination), and they will not fill the available space, only the specified minimum height.

Comment: I basically have a similar problem, though I got it at least partially resolved... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39955551/qt-qgraphicsview-layout-not-shrinking-sizehint-minimumsizehint-etc-not-ca